# Creating an IEnumerable<> from a generator method using a factory function

Tags: c#, linq

I have a factory function, and want to use it to create an Enumerable. In C# I didn't find a straight-forward declarative way to do the job. So I did it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => GenerateRandomContact());
}
```

Is there any better way?

```
// Expected format
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Generate(GenerateRandomContact).Take(5);
}
```

Comment: What would you expect `Enumerable.Generate(GenerateRandomContact)` to return? An enumerable that produces an infinite number of random contacts, hoping that someone will invoke a limiting function (such as `Take`) later in the chain before attempting to enumerate the entire enumeration? That's feasible, although not normally how the Linq functions are supposed to be used.

Comment: I usually just create a List<> object instead of generating a custom IEnumerable type.  So I would just use ListrNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => GenerateRandomContact()).ToList();  With your code how can anybody tell that only 5 numbers are being returned?

Comment: @jdweng: By looking at the docs (same as with your method). Or by invoking [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @msa as @@jdweng said, how do you know that with your expected format which limit number you have the result on a specific amount? you should pass at least that number. Check my answer bellow

Comment: @jdweng: ToList, ToArray, Count ... are the worst extensions ever seen in C#. In our team we classify them as Anti-Patterns. I don't care if a developer decided to write while(true); as I don't care if the same developer decided to call a generator function without a break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate(Func<T> generator)
{
    while(true)
        yield return generator.Invoke();
}
```

But you **can't** extend static classes. So you should place it in a helper class.

Comment: Two things: First, shouldn't this be `public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> generator)` ? `Action<T>` takes one `T` as input and has no output, while `Func<T>` has no input and returns one `T` as output.

Second, while this is an easy way to create any amount of elements, this only works if nobody **ever** calls `ToList()` or you run into an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` will be on the conscience of the caller. Infinite generators are pretty much a thing in functional programming style.

Comment: @msa Thanks for fixing instead of complain about. darkWanderer, how would you limit the results? just by passing a maximum value?

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i ++)
    {
       yield return GenerateRandomContact();
    }
}
```

or if you want a specific amount  you can do this

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get(int number)
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= number; i ++)  //is the same as for (var i = 1;; i++) you got the idea
    {
        yield return GenerateRandomContact();
    }
}
```

You are expecting something like Enumerable.Generate()

In order to get a list of elements that you want to Enumerate, your Generate method should return an Enumerable Value. You are trying to create an extension method for Enumerable based on your approach. Before that try to see the implementation of Range

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) 
{
     long max = ((long)start) + count - 1;
     if (count < 0 || max > Int32.MaxValue) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("count");
            return RangeIterator(start, count);
}

static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return start + i;
}
```

In that case with the yield, .NET creates the IEnumerable class for you and based on a specific amount. Maybe you should consider passing the amount on the Generate method, or like the other extensions as Concat, you should pass the IEnumerable, see bellow how they pass to the Contact mehotd the IEnumerable first variable

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) 
{
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(first, second);
}
```

With that said.

You can use my first approach or your GenerateRandomContact should return an IEnumerable of Contact, but there is the problem, how much elements you want on that Random creation, or you don't specify the amount as bellow

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GenerateRandomContact()
 {

    var random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        yield return new Contact
        {
            Name = $"Name_{random.Next()}"
        };
    }
 }
```

or you pass the parameter

But the whole problem now is, if you want to call your method as Enumerable.Generate, that is not possible, You can't have extension methods on static classes because extension methods are only applicable to instantiable types and static classes cannot be instantiated.

Your call should be

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>(){....}
//where contacts is an instance of type
contacts.Generate
```

even in the case you want this syntax

```
 contacts.Generate(GenerateRandomContact).Take(5);
```

your extension method should accept a function but here I am relying on the previous GenerateRandomContact() where I put 100 random contacts

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<IEnumerable<T>> func)
    {
        if (func != null)
        {
            return func();
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

IMHO try to consider passing the amount that you want to take. Your syntax will change a little bit

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>()
            {
                new Contact
                {
                    Name = "Name1"
                },
                new Contact
                {
                    Name = "Name2"
                }
            }; //load your methods from the database or create them here

            var res = contacts.Generate(GenerateRandomContact, 5);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static IEnumerable<Contact> GenerateRandomContact(int amount)
        {
            var random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                yield return new Contact
                {
                    Name = $"Name_{random.Next()}"
                };
            }
        }

    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> func, int amount)
        {
            if (func != null)
            {
                return func(amount);
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you want more than 5 items?

Comment: change the numbers, same thing he needs to do inside the get, if no, then pass the parameters of the range you want

Comment: This is no different than `Enumerable.Range` + `Select`

Comment: The second method would loop nearly infinitely on 0 or negative inputs. Why not just use `i <= number;`?

Comment: @KelsonBall I did it, but based on a suggestion I was modifying it, but you are right